# SQL table structure to store long list of data for test results

Tags: sql

I am trying to design a SQL table(s) to store the results of a series of tests. I am not certain of how to handle multiple instances of the actual test data as it is a large table in itself. A single test consists of 3 data points sampled up to 2500 times. So as an example the test result looks like this:

```
#       Value 1     Value 2        Value 3
1       21.91108    21.80776867    17.930795
2       21.91247    21.8091134     17.92889429
3       21.91389    21.81048815    17.92581857
4       21.91515    21.81170294    17.92225429
...
1999    21.98995    21.87558687    17.94293
2000    21.99900    21.87678687    17.95294
```

The test will be run multiple times. I have created a table which stores details about each time the test is run, Timestamp, TestID, UserName. My application will eventually allow the user to select a particular TestID and recall that table of data to trend.

My thought was to create a TestData table with the results of all tests and a column with the TestID to query and recall the data from an individual test. Would appreciate any thoughts on this approach or if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your suggestion is fine. I would build a five-column table, with:

```
ID, test #, value 1, value 2, value 3
```

[Test]/[Test Details] would be the same schema you see used for stuff like [orders]/[order details] data storage.

[ID] + [test #] as a key would ensure your data integrity.